# Can not Run Crystal Report XI in VB6

Tags: database, vb6, crystal-reports, connection, report

I have an Old project which is **VB6 but not any source code**. I extract the **DLL** file and find connection string. I configure my PC to give the environment (data source, computer name, windows authentication etc) and finally can run the project with the exe.

But when i run the report it shows an error. Reports are designed using Crystal Report XI.

> Run-time error '-2147189155 (80047e5d)':
>
> Failed to open the connection.

I haven't find any clue. I search and search but can't solve.

Report files are in different folder. The folder contains some **DLL, EXP, OBJ** file.

**Example: Report_SIM_Commercial2.dll, Report_SIM_Commercial2.exp, Cry_Report_Prod_FinalInspOffer_FW.OBJ**

Can any body give me any suggestion.... or any clue to solve the problem...